# Question on irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, irreducible-polynomials

I know the standard definition of an irreducible polynomial. But, in the book "a course in abstract algebra" by authors "Khanna and Bhambri", irreducible polynomial is defined as following:

> Let $R$ be an integral domain with unity. A polynomial $f(x)\in R[x]$ of positive degree(i.e. deg≥1) is said to be an irreducible polynomial over $R$ if it can not be expressed as product of two polynomials of positive degree. In other words if whenever $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, then $\deg g(x)=0$ or $\deg\text h(x)=0$

According to [usual](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial?wprov=sfla1) definition of an irreducible polynomial, $f(x)=2x^2+4=2(x^2+2)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$(reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ because neither $2$ is unit nor $x^2+2$ is unit in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$) . **Hence according to our usual definition, above polynomial is reducible over smaller set $\mathbb{Z}$ but irreducible over bigger set $\mathbb{Q}$**

Whereas, if I use above definition in the book then, $f(x)=2(x^2+2)$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and over  $\mathbb{Z}$ too. **I think this looks more appropriate!  Irreducible in bigger set and hence it must be irreducible in smaller set!**

So which definition is more correct? and is there is disadvantage of using above definition in book?

Comment: Both definitions are equally valid, just make sure you stick to one. I have seen mathematicians use both definitions.

Comment: We had several discussions on the definitions here. You can search for such posts. I found   [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580877/why-is-the-polynomial-2x2-4-reducible-over-mathbbz), but it only considers one definition. See also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581835/irreducible-polynomials-over-mathbb-q-and-mathbb-z).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sir thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the definition that $a$ is irreducible in $R$ if $a=xy$ in $r$ means one of $x$ and $y$ is a unit is more correct.
$x^4 +1$ is irreducible in  $\mathbb{Z}$ but is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}}$ for all $n$ >$1$